# Notions of convergence of real sequences. Where can I learn about this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation-method

I am looking some good references to introduce myself to convergence process of real sequences. I know classical convergence, uniform convergence, almost convergence, matrix summation method, statistical convergence. Are there more convergences? There exists a general convergence that extend all of them?

Comment: It is possible to define convergence more generally, using topologies.

Comment: All the notions I mentioned are particular cases of that convergence you are talking about?

Comment: No, this is impossible. For two notions of convergence in different contexts we cannot always expect a common generalisation. For example, "formal convergence", "statistical convergence" and "universal convergence" are from different contexts and nobody wants to consider a common generalisation (if that's even possible).